# How would I make a slime blob like this image?

Tags: meta-objects

Wondering if anyone knows the best way to build a model like this? I'm new to Blender. I've tried several tutorials, working with the metaballs and such but I can't get it to look right. The aspect I'm missing is the look of the slime realistically pulling in different directions away from the base and thinning out at the connection points.[image]

I feel like this should be pretty easy, but can't seem to find a good tutorial for it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd have also gone the metaball way, failing that perhaps try sculpting it.

Comment: yes metaballs seems the best solution, is it supposed to be animated?

Comment: No, no animation.